# I am trying to plot three lines with matplotlib but it is showing up as one

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DF That I am using to plot how many userlogs a player has had in a given hour. I want to see what time of the day they are most active.

```
    username    hour    freq
0   Player 1    0        74
1   Player 1    1        37
2   Player 1    2        6
3   Player 2    3        152
4   Player 2    5        90
5   Player 2    6        57
6   Player 3    7        219
7   Player 3    8        443
8   Player 3    9        557
```

I then use that DF and try and plot it like this:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10,5
for name in playername: 
    playertimes = new_df[new_df.username.isin([name])]
    plt.plot(playertimes['freq'], c='Black', ls='--', marker = 's', ms=7, label = name)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
plt.xticks(list(range(0,24)), new_df['hour'], rotation = 'vertical')
plt.show()
```

My logic is that I am going to use the playertimes df as a temporary df so I can plot only the freq of each player.

I was hoping for one line for each player but what I got was this:

[Failed Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDTrg.png)

I tried messing with a few things but can not seem to get it to work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of users has to be unique to go through the dataframe just once, and the dataframe should be sorted by 'hour' to display the results as expected. In order to display the proper values on the x axis, you just need to actually plot those values on the x-axis. The code below includes all these changes:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10,5
linestyles = ['-', '--', ':']
markers = ['s', 'o', 'v']
for i, name in enumerate(df.username.unique()): 
    playertimes = df[df.username.isin([name])].sort_values('hour')
    plt.plot(playertimes['hour'], playertimes['freq'], c='Black', 
ls=linestyles[i], marker =markers[i], ms=7, label = name)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
plt.xticks(range(0,24), rotation = 'vertical')
plt.show()
```

[image: 3 plots]

Comment: That was just a sample of the data, In the actual DF it has each player grouped with 0 -23 and then the Freq column.
I tried making the changes on mine and I still get the graph from my post. I wonder why you are getting it correct and I am not.

Comment: I have edited the response now I understand what your problem was.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. Thank you so much.